# why div tag does not work with html and css

Tags: html, css

css `class` does not work in `div` but `id` is working with this css code. I write `class` first and `id` second in my css area and also html tag. why ?

**CSS**

```
.first {
    color:blue;
    background:#ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#second {
    color:green;
    background:red;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="first" id="second">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis.
</div>
``
```

Comment: Have you added a link ref to your css file?

Comment: html and css both are in same file

Comment: do you have a style tag wrapping the css?

Comment: Yes, I have style tag.

Comment: search for `css specificity` and that will help answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSS` does not matter the orders. Here is `css` rules are..

```
1. #id selectors are worth 100
2. .class selectors are worth 10
3. Tag selectors are worth 1
```

That's why `id` is working and `class` does not work in your `html` area.

Answer (score 1):

**Id** is more specific selector than **class**, so it takes precedence over class selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

Because the id selector has a higher priority then the class selector in CSS, so in this case the CSS (whats belong to your id) will overwrite the CSS of your class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several precedence rules for CSS

1. inline css ( html style attribute ) overrides css rules in style tag and css file
2. Rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both have the same specificity.
3. A css rule with !important always takes precedence.